# In the theory of inflation, what does 'thermal equlibrium' mean?

Tags: cosmological-inflation

Baumann writes in his lecture notes on Cosmology,

> 'If the inflaton can decay into bosons, the decay may be very rapid,
> involving a mechanism called parametric resonance (sourced by Bose
> condensation effects). This kind of rapid decay is called preheating,
> since the bosons thus created are far from thermal equilibrium.'

But what exactly does he mean by the bosons being far from thermal equilibrium? In relation to what? Two systems A and B are in thermal equilibrium iff their temperatures T1, T2 are equal. So we have a bath of bosons created from the non-perturbative decay processes of the inflaton field during preheating. This bath has a temperature. But what other system's temperature are we comparing it to?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, thermal equilibrium is between the *particles* that are present and the surrounding bath of *photons* with which the particles are interacting.

Comment: But the photons you speak of, they must first be produced via reheating, don't they? After all, before reheating, the inflaton field had yet to decay into the fields of the standard model of particle physics.

Comment: There were plenty of photons bouncing around right before that. See Weinberg's book "The First Three Minutes" for details.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide me with a page number? I have purchased this book and he doesn't mention inflation until the very end in the afterword, much less reheating or even preheating.